# PWA progressive web app, cache of index.php is that possible

Tags: caching, service, worker

I have a responsive site, that I enhanced creating a PWA progressive web app. My index is index.php I wonder how can I cache that page on Service Worker if the usual is html such as  index.html… what can I do to make an index.html for offline view which my show  about us, addrees and basic stuff.